# Cylinder inside a cylinder - moment of inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

> A homogeneous cylinder with radius **a** and mass **m** rolls in a hollow cylinder with radius R. Determine the kinetic energy of the cylinder as function of $\dot{\theta}$.
>
> [image]

I'm sorry for reposting this, but I found this question this morning while browsing and tried myself to it, but didn't get even an approach. I would have commented on the original post but I don't have enough reputation yet (no idea how to get reputation).

Anyway, my thoughts so far:

Since the inner cylinder does not slide I can assume $v=r\dot{\theta}$, right? As the original poster I was thinking that the kinetic energy in this case would be the rotational energy, so $E=I\dot{\theta}^2=\frac{1}{2}MR^2\dot{\theta}^2$. But then again, the problem says to determine the kinetic energy as a function of $\dot{\theta}$, which means that the rotational energy is not constant.

I don't know how to approach this. Anyone got any tips?

Comment: In the equation $v=r\dot{\theta}$, what are $v$ and $r$ supposed to represent? Also if the kinetic energy is just the rotational energy, doesn't this mean you would have no kinetic energy if there was no friction between the two cylinders, so that the inner one didn't rotate? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Crossposted from http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339338/11127

Comment: What is missing from the question is the assumption of _rolling without slipping_. Hence the two angles noted are kinematically linked. More importantly, their rate of change (rotational speed) are _linearly_ related to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You correctly identified there are two angles of interest, labeled $\theta$ and $\phi$. I actually want to pick two different angles for my analysis - see this diagram:

[image]

First thing to note is that if the cylinder rolls without sliding, the length of the green arc and the red arc must be the same.

Length of green arc: $(\phi + \theta) a$

Length of red arc: $\theta R$

$$(\phi + \theta) a = \theta R\\
\theta = \frac{a}{R-a}\phi$$

(You could put a minus sign in there - the rotation for one is clockwise when the other is anticlockwise). The total energy of the cylinder is the rotational energy ($\frac12 I \dot\phi^2$) plus the linear kinetic energy $\frac12 m v^2 = \frac12 m ((R-a)\dot\theta)^2$

You can simplify this (express everything in terms of $\theta$) and set the sum of kinetic and potential energy constant. You end up with an equation for simple harmonic motion (for small displacements) with an apparently greater inertia (longer period) than would be expected from a mass at the end of a string of length $R-a$ ;

See how far you get with that nudge.

Comment: Could you explain where the equation $\theta = \dfrac{a}{R} \phi$ comes from? How does that follow from setting $\theta =\phi =0$?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs - I was a bit too quick... added a diagram and derivation of formula. Changed definition of $\phi$ so it represents the rotation of the inner cylinder in the world frame of reference

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs since all we really need is the relationship between $d\theta$ and $d\phi$, consider that when $\theta$ increases by $d\theta$, the cylinder will have rotated by an arc length $R d\theta = a d\phi$.

Comment: @EricAngle I wanted to see a more detailed justification of that result. See Floris's edit. He/She made a nice picture explaining it.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs - I want to give a shout-out for the "He/She" in your comment. As the father of a daughter who is doing a Master's in physics, I see first hand how hard it is for women to be accepted as equals in this field - [they face challenges that go beyond the physics itself](http://www.theguardian.com/science/occams-corner/2015/jun/19/just-one-action-for-women-in-science); it all starts with small steps like not making assumptions about gender. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how $\theta = a \phi / \left(R-a\right)$ is right. Consider the case where the small cylinder makes a full revolution within the big cylinder: $\theta \rightarrow \theta' = \theta + \Delta \theta = \theta + 2\pi$. $\phi$ should then increase by $\Delta \theta \times$ the ratio of the circumferences: $\phi \rightarrow \phi' = \phi + 2 \pi R / a$. This is precisely what $R d\theta = a d\phi$ gives.

Comment: @EricAngle - it's possible I got it wrong, but I define $\phi$ as the angle rotated _in the lab frame_, not relative to the radial vector. I tried to indicate this in my diagram. As $a\rightarrow R$ the inner disk will rotate less and less for a full revolution around the inner cylinder.

Comment: @EricAngle Floris gives a correct proof of why the relationship is what it is in the answer. Also, another way of proving is to say that rolling without slipping means the point in contact with the wall is not moving. This point's velocity can be expressed as the sum of two pieces: a piece from the center of mass velocity $v$ of the cylinder and a piece from the angular velocity $\omega$ of the cylinder. We find that $v-\omega a=0$. Substituting $v=(R-a)\dot{\theta}$, we get the same result. Also consider the case where $a$ is only barely smaller than $r$. [continued]

Comment: @EricAngle In the case where $a$ is just barely smaller than $R$, it should be obvious that as $\theta$ rotates through an angle of $2 \pi$, $\phi$ only changes a little bit (consistent with our formula), but you would say $\phi$ rotates a full $2 \pi$.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs I like the argument that the cylinder moves with speed $v = \left(R-a\right) \dot{\theta} = a \dot{\phi}$. Also, if you consider the case $a = R/2$, you can see that the small cylinder will make a single revolution, which agrees with your expression, but not mine.

Comment: @EricAngle - so are we all agreed?